# json returning list

Tags: jquery

I want to see an example of how to consume out of domain json service that returns list of items.

Can anyone point me towards a 'real' example to see how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
      });
    });
```

Not entirely sure what you mean by 'consume the service', but this loads the four most recent cat pictures from the Flickr JSONP API.

[source](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON)